# Como suportar colunas adicionadas pelo utilizador sem atualizar o model de EF?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Tenho uma aplicação `C#` com um model *Entity Framework 6 "Database First"* criado a partir da estrutura base de uma banco de dados *SQL Server*, que pertence a um software de terceiros.

Os utilizadores desse software podem adicionar campos de utilizador a algumas tabelas, definindo o seu nome e tipo de dados, que são adicionados a tabela em SQL Server.

**Exemplo:** numa implementação, o cliente pode adicionar a tabela Produtos um campo u_cor do tipo nvarchar, na outra, implementação o cliente pode adicionar a tabela Produtos uma coluna u_dataPrimeiraCompra do tipo datetime.

Esta tabela Produtos terá assim um conjunto de colunas presente em todas as implementações do software, mas em cada implementação podem ser adicionadas colunas específicas dessa implementação.

***A minha questão é:*** Há alguma forma de, em tempo de execução, informar o model da existência de colunas adicionais, exemplo: definindo-as num ficheiro *.config*, de modo a que possa atribuir ou recuperar valores dessas colunas adicionais, ou de outro modo mais "direto" atribuir valores a essas colunas, mesmo sem as espelhar no modelo?

Comment: Se for para você fazer isso amigo, utilize sem Entity Framework isso é uma recomendação, porque, se for pra digitar SQL natural, não vejo necessidades nenhuma de utilizar um ORM. Utilizar só para fazer conexão é um grande erro!

Answer (score 4):

Acho que o Entity Framework não vai se importar com as colunas adicionais, desde que elas não
atrapalhem o salvamento das entidades sem os valores adicionais.

### Adicionando colunas sem atrapalhar o Entity

Para isso basta setar um valor default para os campos adicionais, criando-as com SQL puro mesmo.

Você teria que armazenar quais colunas adicionais existem. Pode até ser no banco de dados mesmo,
digamos em uma tabela chamada `ExtraColumns`, a qual poderia ser lida pelo Entity Framework e
mapeada normalmente para uma classe `ExtraColumn`.

```cs
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    // pegando o ObjectContext
    var objectContext = context is DbContext
         ? ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext
         : context as ObjectContext;

    var isNullable = false;
    var nomeTabela = "Produtos";
    var nomeColuna = "NovaColuna"; // NOTA: se essa string vier do usuário então será
                                   // necessário validar o texto para evitar SQL Injection
    // Exemplo: permitir apenas letras
    if (nomeColuna.Any(ch => !char.IsLetter(ch)))
        throw new Exception("Senhor usuário, o nome da coluna permite apenas letras.");

    var tipoColuna = "nvarchar(max)";

    objectContext.ExecuteStoreCommand(string.Format(@"
        ALTER TABLE {0} 
        ADD [{1}] {2} {3} 
        CONSTRAINT DEFAULT_{0}_{1} DEFAULT {4}
    ", nomeTabela, nomeColuna, tipoColuna, isNullable ? "NULL" : "NOT NULL", valorDefault));

    var extraColumn = new ExtraColumn
    {
        NomeTabela = nomeTabela,
        NomeColuna = nomeColuna,
        TipoColuna = tipoColuna,
    }
    context.ExtraColumns.Add(extraColumn);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

### Recuperando valores das colunas extra

Para recuperar valores nesses campos adicionais, você pode usar a própria conexão usada pelo
`DbContext` ou `ObjectContext`, mas sem passar pelo ORM em si, usando a própria conexão com
o banco de dados e criando um `DbCommand` e depois um `DbDataReader`:

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    // pegando o ObjectContext
    var objectContext = context is DbContext
         ? ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext
         : context as ObjectContext;

    var nomeTabela = "Produtos";

    var extraColumns = context.ExtraColumns
        .Where(c => c.NomeTabela == nomeTabela)
        .ToList();

    var query = "SELECT "
        + string.Join(",", extraColumns.Select(c => c.NomeColuna))
        + " FROM " + nomeTabela;

    // pegando a conexão com o DB a partir do ObjectContext
    var conn = ((EntityConnection)objectContext.Connection).StoreConnection;

    using (var command = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = query;
        var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // reader[0] agora contém a primeira coluna extra
            // reader[1] agora contém a segunda coluna extra
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

### Salvando valores das colunas extra

Para salvar valores nesses campos adicionais, você pode usar o método `ExecuteStoreCommand`,
como fizemos antes para criar as novas colunas:

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    // pegando o ObjectContext
    var objectContext = context is DbContext
         ? ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext
         : context as ObjectContext;

    var nomeTabela = "Produtos";
    var values = __lista_de_valores_a_atualizar__;

    var extraColumns = context.ExtraColumns
        .Where(c => c.NomeTabela == nomeTabela)
        .ToList();

    var queryFmt = "UPDATE "
        + string.Join(",", extraColumns.Select((c, i) => string.Format("{0} = {{{1}}}", c.NomeColuna, i))
        + " FROM " + nomeTabela;

    // NOTA: O método abaixo NÃO é suscetível a SQL Injection
    objectContext.ExecuteStoreCommand(queryFmt, values.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: Obrigado @Miguel Angelo , estou espantado com a clareza da sua resposta, logo que tenha tempo testá-la-ei e darei feedback :)

Comment: Faça isso, pois não sei se vai funcionar assim de cara... mas o conceito é mais ou menos esse. Talvez esteja faltando algum detalhe, ai é só por um comentário aqui, que vejo uma forma de ajudar.