# EF Core - Mapear colunas dinâmicas para uma lista

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Preciso de uma ajuda no mapeamento de entidades do EF Core.

Tenho tabela **produtos** e essa tabela pode conter colunas diferentes dependendo na customização do cliente, serão sempre colunas texto. Eu tenho uma tabela e uma entidade chamada **Label** onde me diz qual o nome da coluna na tabela de produtos. Preciso mapear isso para uma lista de Label dentro da entidade de Produto.

**Tabela de Produto**

-id

-titulo

-codigo_a

-codigo_b

**Tabela Label**

-id
-nomeColuna
-titulo

Tenhos os registros na tabela label:

1 - codigo_a - Codigo A

2 - codigo_b - Codigo B

Comment: Não entendi direito o que você precisa, poderia exemplificar melhor?

Comment: Veja esse gist: https://gist.github.com/eabreusantos/cf7383c1cd9f5fc166a31e3045c6b20d  oq eu preciso é mapear colunas da msm tabela para uma lista na entidade, mas quais colunas serão definidas por registros em outra tabela.

Comment: É algo parecido com isso: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13015/como-suportar-colunas-adicionadas-pelo-utilizador-sem-atualizar-o-model-de-ef?rq=1 mas utilizando o mapeamento do proprio EF.